# how to remove multiple col values base on a list

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataset df that looks like this:

[image]

if I want to move any value that is in the list RM. What should I do?

The df and RM can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(cy3.CSV = c("cy3.CSV", NA, NA), cy6.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", 
"cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), dlt.CSV = c("dlt.CSV", NA, NA), dm.CSV = c("dm.CSV", 
NA, NA), dov.CSV = c("dov.CSV", "dov_1.CSV", NA), dov_1.CSV = c("dov_1.CSV", 
NA, NA), ds.CSV = c("ds.CSV", "ds_1.CSV", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

RM <-c("chem.CSV",  "dov_1.CSV", "eot_p.CSV", "dm.CSV', "vs.CSV")
```

The outcome should be something looks like

[image]

what should I do? please give me as many possible solution as you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub(paste0(RM, collapse = '|'), NA, x)))
  cy3.CSV  cy6.CSV dlt.CSV dm.CSV dov.CSV dov_1.CSV   ds.CSV
1 cy3.CSV  cy1.CSV dlt.CSV   <NA> dov.CSV      <NA>   ds.CSV
2    <NA> cy24.CSV    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>      <NA> ds_1.CSV
3    <NA>  cy6.CSV    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
```

Using purrr and stringr packages:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_df(df, ~ str_replace_all(.x, str_c(RM, collapse = '|'), NA_character_))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  cy3.CSV cy6.CSV  dlt.CSV dm.CSV dov.CSV dov_1.CSV ds.CSV  
  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
1 cy3.CSV cy1.CSV  dlt.CSV NA     dov.CSV NA        ds.CSV  
2 NA      cy24.CSV NA      NA     NA      NA        ds_1.CSV
3 NA      cy6.CSV  NA      NA     NA      NA        NA
```

Comment: This should work. Is it possible to list it as NA as well? I just want sth same as other empty cell.

Comment: @Stataq, have updated my answer, please check if that works.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `across` with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . %in% RM, NA)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  cy3.CSV cy6.CSV  dlt.CSV dm.CSV dov.CSV dov_1.CSV ds.CSV  
#  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
#1 cy3.CSV cy1.CSV  dlt.CSV <NA>   dov.CSV <NA>      ds.CSV  
#2 <NA>    cy24.CSV <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>      ds_1.CSV
#3 <NA>    cy6.CSV  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
```